# Django {{ block.super }} not working in a particular case

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm trying to extend a template which contains this block:

```
    {% block headerjs %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

To extend it, I'm using `{{ block.super }}` :

```
{% block headerjs %}
{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/formhandler.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

It is not working, {{ block.super }} is empty. I have noticed that `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>` is the reason. When I don't load this script, everything works fine. Does anyone know why?

Comment: what if you put it into quotes: `{% url "django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog" %}`?

Comment: are you extending from the right base template ?

Comment: Is your javascript catalog url tag resolving correctly?  For example, what do you see in the HTML if you render the parent template?

Comment: Thank you! It was the quotes as @alecxe pointed out. It is weird, before I was not extending the template but just using the base and it was working without quotes. Anyway, is this enough to render     {{ block.super}} as empty?

Comment: Did you have the TEMPLATE_DEBUG value in your settings.py to True? If not, sometimes it'll suppress those kinds of errors during development.

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 1.5, you have to **put quotes around views names** in the `{% url %}` template tag. Otherwise, it'll be considered as a context variable now (so it'll search the variable `django` if exists and get its attribute `views` and so on...).
The correct version, as pointed out in comments is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog' %}"></script>
```

Maybe it was working before because you were using Django <= 1.4.